# Python: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found want output in CSV format

Tags: python, csv

code.py is as below:

```
import os


nextLineIsATimestamp = False
newBlock = False
blocks = []
block = []
formattedLine = None
ts = None
index = 0

if os.path.exists("new_destination.csv"):
  os.remove("new_destination.csv")
else:
  print("The file does not exist")

writer = open("new_destination.csv", "a")

with open('source.log', 'r') as reader:

  for line in reader:
    index +=1

    formattedLine = line.replace(" ", ',').split(",")
    formattedLine = filter(None, formattedLine)

    if '----' in line:
      newBlock = True

    if newBlock is True:
      newBlock = False
    elif nextLineIsATimestamp:
      # this is a new block, this is a timestamp
      ts = formattedLine[0]
      # reset the state
      nextLineIsATimestamp = False
    else:
      block.extend(formattedLine)
      block.append(ts)
      writer.write(",".join(block))

    formattedLine = None


writer.close()
```

source file from data reading is done as "source.log"

```
----
05-19-2020_02:59:41
root     26995  0.0  0.3 235580 14116 ?        Ss   May18   0:00 sshd: avi_fivetran_com [priv]
avi_fiv+ 27011  0.0  0.1 235580  5008 ?        S    May18   0:00 sshd: avi_fivetran_com@pts/0
root     27543  0.0  0.3 232880 13412 ?        Ss   May18   0:00 sshd: fivetran [priv]
fivetran 27750  0.0  0.1 232880  5040 ?        S    May18   0:01 sshd: fivetran
root     32255  0.0  0.3 232880 13580 ?        Ss   01:51   0:00 sshd: fivetran [priv]
fivetran 32427  0.0  0.1 232880  5164 ?        S    01:51   0:00 sshd: fivetran
----
```

output should be in following format "destination.csv"

```
root,26995,0.0,0.3,235580,14116,?,Ss,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com,[priv],05-19-2020_02:59:41
avi_fiv+,27011,0.0,0.1,235580,5008,?,S,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com@pts/0,05-19-2020_02:59:41
root,27543,0.0,0.3,232880,13412,?,Ss,May18,0:00,sshd:,fivetran,[priv],05-19-2020_02:59:41
fivetran,27750,0.0,0.1,232880,5040,?,S,May18,0:01,sshd:,fivetran,05-19-2020_02:59:41
root,32255,0.0,0.3,232880,13580,?,Ss,01:51,0:00,sshd:,fivetran,[priv],05-19-2020_02:59:41
fivetran,32427,0.0,0.1,232880,5164,?,S,01:51,0:00,sshd:,fivetran,05-19-2020_02:59:41
root,26995,0.0,0.3,235580,14116,?,Ss,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com,[priv],05-19-2020_02:59:51
avi_fiv+,27011,0.0,0.1,235580,5008,?,S,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com@pts/0,0
```

but getting the following error message:

```
$ python code.py.orig
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py.orig", line 40, in <module>
    writer.write(",".join(block))
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, NoneType found
```

So I changed the code.py line as below:

before change:

```
writer.write(",".join(block))
```

After change:

```
writer.write(",".join(str(block)))
```

I want the output to be like as 'destination.csv' but it is including " , " after every word rather than columns. any help would be greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: If you have ------ in your line, you set newBlock to True, then immediately again to False.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yes. that is there in the .py script. Do I need to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with tabular data, I recommend using Pandas. Something like this should do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('source.log', header=None, skiprows=[0, 1], skipfooter=1)
df.to_csv('destination.csv', header=None)
```

`cat destination.csv` gives:

```
0,root,26995,0.0,0.3,235580,14116,?,Ss,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com [priv]
1,avi_fiv+,27011,0.0,0.1,235580,5008,?,S,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com@pts/0
2,root,27543,0.0,0.3,232880,13412,?,Ss,May18,0:00,sshd:,fivetran [priv]
3,fivetran,27750,0.0,0.1,232880,5040,?,S,May18,0:01,sshd:,fivetran
4,root,32255,0.0,0.3,232880,13580,?,Ss,01:51,0:00,sshd:,fivetran [priv]
5,fivetran,32427,0.0,0.1,232880,5164,?,S,01:51,0:00,sshd:,fivetran
```

EDIT: removing the index and adding the date.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('source.log', header=None, skiprows=[0, 1], skipfooter=1)

with open('source.log', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
date = lines[1].replace('\n', '')
df['date'] = date

df.to_csv('destination.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

to get:

```
root,26995,0.0,0.3,235580,14116,?,Ss,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com [priv],05-19-2020_02:59:41
avi_fiv+,27011,0.0,0.1,235580,5008,?,S,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com@pts/0,05-19-2020_02:59:41
root,27543,0.0,0.3,232880,13412,?,Ss,May18,0:00,sshd:,fivetran [priv],05-19-2020_02:59:41
fivetran,27750,0.0,0.1,232880,5040,?,S,May18,0:01,sshd:,fivetran,05-19-2020_02:59:41
root,32255,0.0,0.3,232880,13580,?,Ss,01:51,0:00,sshd:,fivetran [priv],05-19-2020_02:59:41
fivetran,32427,0.0,0.1,232880,5164,?,S,01:51,0:00,sshd:,fivetran,05-19-2020_02:59:41
```

Comment: Thank you, @anthony-khong. I created a new file called 'code1.py' and I installed 'pip install wheel and pip install pandas' but when I run the script again 'python code1.py' it complains about ''ImportError: No module named pandas". Any help?

Comment: Thank you, @anthony-khong. I created a new file called 'code1.py' and I installed 'pip install wheel and pip install pandas' but when I run the script again 'python code1.py' it complains about ''ImportError: No module named pandas". Any help?
'No module name pandas' resolved by issuing following 2 commands:
"sudo python3.7 -m pip install wheel"
"sudo python3.7 -m pip install pandas"
Now script worked fine but need output as:
```
root,26995,0.0,0.3,235580,14116,?,Ss,May18,0:00,sshd:,avi_fivetran_com,[priv],05-19-2020_02:59:41
```

Comment: Okay, I'm seeing two differences here: i) you don't want the index on the first column and ii) you'd like the final column to be the datetime. I've updated the answer to do this.

Comment: thank you. that resolved the issue in a clear way to use pandas vs other python library when we have 'tabular data' in the source.log file and output which csv.